# How to validate the date of birth in textformfield with dd/mm/yyyy pattern | Flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, date

How to validate the textformfield of date of birth. I want the user to input the date of birth in the format dd/mm/yyyy (eg: 24/02/1998) like this. How i can give validation to it. Also i need when the user type first day the "/" should automatically print on textformfield.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to validate the user. When the user submit input you can manipulate the data.

```
formater(){
    var now = new DateTime.now(); //or u can pass the input text like _textController.text
    var formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    print(formatted);
  }
```

This returns; 26-02-2021

Dont forget to implement the **intl** package //import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021
Easy way, just using packages: **flutter_masked_text**

```
var controller = new MaskedTextController(mask: '00/00');
```